# Is it possible to prove this more general variant of Zorn's lemma?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I would like to ask if it is possible to prove this more general variant of Zorn's lemma? If possible, please don't post your proof. I will try to prove it by myself first.

1. Zorn's Lemma

> Suppose that $(A,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set in which each chain has an upper bound. Then $A$ has a maximal element.

2. My variant

> Suppose that $(A,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set in which each chain has an upper bound, and that $C$ is a chain in $A$. Then there exists a maximal $m$ of $A$ such that $c \leq m$ for all $c \in C$.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. This is possible, but how do you know to trust me? I haven't given you the proof of my claim. Either try and prove this, or ask for a proof. There's little point in asking if this can be proved or not...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I trust you without reservation! I found this as an exercise in my textbook, but I'm not sure if this exercise is correct or not.  I try to prove and post my proof to receive your comment :v

Comment: Don't trust me without reservation, and you can trust me without reservation when I tell you that. :)

Comment: If there is mistake or typo in this exercise, OMG i will waste my time for an impossible task!

Comment: And in that case if you can't prove it, then you've done a very good job of not lying to yourself. Mathematics is a lot about what you might call a wasted effort, but these efforts are not wasted, they help you build confidence in your own abilities, as well as intuition and other tools of facing difficulties.

Comment: @AsafKaragila http://conradhotels3.hilton.com/en_US/ch/search/findhotels/index.htm this should help with the reservation. (My timing was a bit off..)

Comment: @NotMike: I see what you did there. Clever.

Comment: Yes there is a proof and it uses chains of chains, i.e. nests of chains.

Comment: Take all chains that contain $c$ and order by inclusion. Then apply Zorn.

Comment: Even simpler: Take some upper bound $u$ of the chain $c$ and verify that the assumptions of Zorn's lemma apply to the subset of elements larger or equal to $u$. Show that a maximal element of this subset will do the trick.

Comment: What @Michael suggested is the simplest path I had in mind: first prove that Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the strengthening from "There is a maximal element" to "Above any point there is a maximal element", then take any upper bound of $C$ and apply the stronger Zorn's lemma. (I didn't want to write it out in details, but since everyone already spilled the beans on how to prove this...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I have posted my proofs as an answer (since it is too long), please have a look at them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of @drhab and @Michael comments, I have formalized my proofs. Please have a check if these two proofs are fine or not. Thank you so much!

1. @drhab approach

> Let $T=\{D \subseteq A \mid  C \subseteq D \wedge D \text{ is a chain}\}$. Then $(T,\subseteq)$ is a partially ordered set.
>
> Assume $X$ is a chain in $T$. Let $Y=\cup_{x \in X}x$. Then $Y \in T$ and Y is an upper bound of $X$. As a result, $(T,\subseteq)$ satisfies condition of Zorn’s lemma. Hence $T$ has a maximal element $\bar{C}$.
>
> Let $c$ be an upper bound of $\bar{C}$. Then $c$ is also an upper bound of $C$.
>
> We now prove that $c$ is a maximal element of $A$. Assume $c < c'$.
>   Then $\bar{C} \cup \{c’\} \in T$ and $\bar{C} \subsetneq \bar{C} \cup
>  \{c’\}$. This contradicts the fact that $\bar{C}$ is a maximal element of $T$. As a result, $c \nless c'$ for all $c' \in A$.
>
> To sum up, $c$ is an upper bound of $C$ and a maximal element of $A$.

2. @Michael approach

> Let $u$ be an upper bound of $C$ and $T=\{x \in A \mid u \leq x\}$.
>
> Assume $X$ is a chain in $T$. Then $X$ has an upper bound in $T$.
>   As a result,  $(T,\leqslant)$ satisfies condition of Zorn’s lemma.
>   Hence $T$ has a maximal element $c$. $c \in T \implies c$ is an upper bound of $C$.
>
> We now prove that $c$ is a maximal element of $A$. Assume $c < c'$. This contradicts the fact that $c$ is a maximal element of $T$. As a result, $c \nless c'$ for all $c' \in A$.
>
> To sum up, $c$ is an upper bound of $C$ and a maximal element of $A$.